# Bash script to extract keywords from current directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a directory in the following format:

```
/folder1/folder2/name_X_Y_Z_A
```

where `X` is a number, `Y`, `Z`, and `A` are 3 or 4 character long strings.

I want to write a shell script file that does the following:

- extract `X` and `Z` from the folder name
- create the string `/folder1/folder2/name_(X-1)_Y_Z_A`
- copy the file `string_Z.dat` from that directory

I'm lost as to how to extract specific patterns from `$PWD`. The character positions of `X` and `Z` don't have to be the same, as the number length and the length of `name` can vary.

Comment: the key point being that the last element of the directory has those pieces separated by underscores?

Comment: Something like `IFS=_ read -a arr <<< "${PWD##*/}"` maybe? then use `${arr[1]}` and `${arr[3]}` to build the new name

Comment: @steeldriver yes, that works perfectly! Thanks :) Can you post this as an answer? Also, how can I get the number right before the first underscore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first trim the leading path components using the shell's parameter substitution syntax `${PWD##*/}`, then read the basename into an array using underscores as a field separator:

```
IFS=_ read -a arr <<< "${PWD##*/}"
```

Since bash arrays are zero-indexed, the parts you want should be in `${arr[1]}` and `${arr[3]}` e.g.

```
newdir="/folder1/folder2/name_$((${arr[1]}-1))_${arr[3]}_Z_A"
```

[Note: I have assumed that you mean the arithmetic result of `(X-1)` rather than the literal string.]

Comment: Just curious: if it was `nameX` instead of `name_X`, is there a way to get the last two characters of `${arr[1]}`?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate in that case, `name10` would be in the zeroth element, and you could extract the 2-character substring starting 2 chars from the end using `"${arr[0]:(-2):2}"` I think

Comment: Thanks. When I do `echo ${arr[0]:(-2):2}-1`, the result is `12-1`, not `11`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate to evaluate the expression arithmetically, you need to surround it with double parentheses `$(( ... ))` e.g. `"$((${arr[0]:(-2):2}-1))"`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that X,Y,Z,A don't have any underscores in them then we can "cut off" the tail each time

eg

```
# DIR=$PWD
# example:
DIR=/folder1/folder2/name_100_YYYY_ZZZZ_AAAA

A=${DIR##*_} ; DIR=${DIR%_*}
Z=${DIR##*_} ; DIR=${DIR%_*}
Y=${DIR##*_} ; DIR=${DIR%_*}
X=${DIR##*_} ; DIR=${DIR%_*}

let X=X-1
DIR="${DIR}_${X}_${Y}_${Z}_${A}"

echo $DIR
```

The other way we can do this is to work out where `X` ends and strip off the rest in one go:

```
# DIR=$PWD
# example:
DIR=/folder1/folder2/name_100_YYYY_ZZZZ_AAAA

DIRX=${DIR%_*_*_*}

YZA=${DIR#$DIRX}
X=${DIRX##*_} ; DIRX=${DIRX%_*}

let X=X-1
DIR="${DIRX}_${X}${YZA}"

echo $DIR
```

In both cases we get `/folder1/folder2/name_99_YYYY_ZZZZ_AAAA` as the result.  You can easily `cp` your file into there.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use python:

```
$ pwd=/folder1/folder1/name_10_ABCD_ABC_ABCD # or use $PWD
$ new=$(python -c "import os; x='"$pwd"'.rsplit('/', 1)[1].split('_'); x[1]=str(int(x[1])+1); print('_'.join(x))")
$ echo $new
name_11_ABCD_ABC_ABCD
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's good to know I can do this, but I'd rather rely on `bash` only.